# Change the Background color of a Windows gripper control

Tags: windows, controls, background-color

I need to set the background color of a window sizing gripper control, which we're doing with:

`DrawFrameControl(hdc, &rect, DFC_SCROLL, DFCS_SCROLLSIZEGRIP);`

It doesn't appear to get any of the WM_CTLCOLOR* messages. I tried filling the window in WM_ERASEBKGND and returning TRUE, but that doesn't work.

I can paint it myself, but it seems like this would be unnecessary to just change the BG color.

Any ideas?